# Implement ILogger interface the right way

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, architecture

Given several types of class constructor injection, i.e.;

```
public class DataService :IDataService
{
    public DataService(ILogger logger) { ... }
}
```

and,

```
public class Logger
{
     public Logger(IDataService service) { ... }
}
```

or, should I do this instead;

```
public class DataService : IDataService, ILogger, IDisposable
{
    public DataService() { ... }
}
```

However, I actually don't like to do this on every repository classes or other classes that needs data services and logging at the same time;

```
public class SomeRepository : IRepostiory
{
    public SomeRepository (IDataService service, ILogger logger) { ... }
}
```

I'm fine with this model;

```
public interface IRepository : ILogger { ... }
```

or,

```
public interface IDataService : ILogger { ... }
```

Which one is preferred as best practice design? Also, how do we determine if we would like to log the data service process, and at the same time we also would like to log other components that injected ILogger services or using repository?

Comment: Why does your logger need idataservice? Just ask as thats a circular reference.. Nasty!:( also, i assume the logger implements ilogger, might be wrong!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the purpose of the `DataService`, i'm sensing you chose inefficient design.

Comment: Normally, you inject to the constructor, or to the method that needs whatever you are injecting.

Comment: @ChrisWatts, Ah, okay. I need the data services for saving the log to database. No, its not circular reference, the question is to choose which one is better. Only one of the types is in the project. I know I can directly do this in the logger for the database, and that is why I would like to know how to do this.

Comment: @OrelEraki, sure, I need the data services for my repository. The data service can be any storage connector. Probably the naming not suitable here. Anyway, the context of the questions is which better and how to implement logging with database if I want to log something inside the data services as well.

Comment: @Riza, perhaps saving the log to somewhere else should be the concern of a log manager? There could be a lot of logic to move or delete etc.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand as is. Perhaps you should just focus on describing the original problem rather than presenting the various solutions you found and asking which one is best. That's usually the wrong way of asking questions... XY problem.

Comment: I suggest considering the [proxy pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx), and/or using [interception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178467(v=pandp.30).aspx) rather than injecting your logger into each repository. [Cross-cutting concerns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658105.aspx) (such as logging) should generally not be part of your actual service implementation.

Comment: @NightOwl888 okay, thanks. Let me have a look. I use event sourcing and CQRS on my projects to overcome logging mechanism, however my question above is for knowledge and best practices.

Comment: @plalx this question is for my better understanding architecture and for knowledge base. Thanks for commenting anyway. And sorry if my question is abstract.

Comment: @Riza Just state what you are trying to achieve. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tongue in cheek answer, but there is no "right" way to implement ILogger. You should probably use the existing framework to construct an `ILogger`, or hand it over to NLog, log4net, or Serilog. You shouldn't directly implement `ILogger` unless you plan to build your own logging framework. You should use the logging libary's extension methods to wireup the `ILogger` Here is an [article](https://christianfindlay.com/2020/07/03/ilogger/) about this.

Here is a minimal example of how to get console logging up and running:

```
var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().
ConfigureLogging((builderContext, loggingBuilder) =>
{
    loggingBuilder.AddConsole((options) =>
    {
        //This displays arguments from the scope
        options.IncludeScopes = true;
    });
});
var host = hostBuilder.Build();
var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<LogTest>>();
//This specifies that every time a log message is logged, the correlation id will be logged as part of it
using (logger.BeginScope("Correlation ID: {correlationID}", 123))
{
    logger.LogInformation("Test");
    logger.LogInformation("Test2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll like to add that the BeginScope method could take any kind of object, not only string. You may pass a more complex object that could represent better the context/scope, like User Id, HostName, CorrelationId, Tennant Id ...

In my case where a created an external Api Logger service, and thus create my own ILogger where BeginScope with those values make more sense.

```
public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
{
    _scopeContextManager = state as ScopeContextManager;
    return default!;
}

public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, 
     Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
{
    // use _scopeContextManager 
}
```

I struggled for a long time before figuring this out.